# Cannot install docker in a RHEL server

Tags: linux, docker, centos7, rhel, rhel7

I am getting `Requires: fuse-overlayfs >= 0.7` error while installing `docker` in RHEL-7.

```
sudo yum install docker-ce
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks, product-id, search-disabled-repos, subscription-manager

This system is not registered with an entitlement server. You can use subscription-manager to register.

Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * epel: mirrors.syringanetworks.net
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package docker-ce.x86_64 3:20.10.2-3.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: containerd.io >= 1.4.1 for package: 3:docker-ce-20.10.2-3.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: docker-ce-cli for package: 3:docker-ce-20.10.2-3.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: docker-ce-rootless-extras for package: 3:docker-ce-20.10.2-3.el7.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package containerd.io.x86_64 0:1.4.3-3.1.el7 will be installed
---> Package docker-ce-cli.x86_64 1:20.10.2-3.el7 will be installed
---> Package docker-ce-rootless-extras.x86_64 0:20.10.2-3.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: fuse-overlayfs >= 0.7 for package: docker-ce-rootless-extras-20.10.2-3.el7.x86_64
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: docker-ce-rootless-extras-20.10.2-3.el7.x86_64 (docker-ce-stable)
           Requires: fuse-overlayfs >= 0.7
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around
```

I already tried

```
sudo rpm -Uvh http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/extras/x86_64/Packages/fuse-overlayfs-0.7.2-6.el7_8.x86_64.rpm
Retrieving http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/extras/x86_64/Packages/fuse-overlayfs-0.7.2-6.el7_8.x86_64.rpm
warning: /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.TZLjHD: Header V3 RSA/SHA256 Signature, key ID f4a80eb5: NOKEY
error: Failed dependencies:
    libfuse3.so.3()(64bit) is needed by fuse-overlayfs-0.7.2-6.el7_8.x86_64
    libfuse3.so.3(FUSE_3.0)(64bit) is needed by fuse-overlayfs-0.7.2-6.el7_8.x86_64
    libfuse3.so.3(FUSE_3.2)(64bit) is needed by fuse-overlayfs-0.7.2-6.el7_8.x86_64
```

Answer (score 111, accepted):

Building on top of @user3495504's answer, what we did to fix the problem was adding an entry on top of the file `/etc/yum.repos.d/docker-ce.repo`, with this content:

```
[centos-extras]
name=Centos extras - $basearch
baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/extras/x86_64
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=http://centos.org/keys/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-7
```

Then the installation command:

```
yum -y install slirp4netns fuse-overlayfs container-selinux
```

was successful.

[Edit]

- enabled gpgcheck

Comment: A little nervous about adding this CentOS repo to my RHEL server :) but it worked

Comment: Thanks, work for me too! 

but maybe it will be better if we enable gpg check ?

```
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=https://www.centos.org/keys/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-7
```

and for me, there's no need to explicitly run `yum -y install slirp4netns fuse-overlayfs container-selinux`

Comment: @keith-ang I agree, that sounds like a safer approach to me.

Comment: I needed a "http://" in front of centos.org... after pgpkey=

Comment: libfuse3.so.3 still required with airgapped install

Comment: worked like a charm, dang thanks so much.

Comment: I also need to set 'notify_only=0' in /etc/yum/pluginconf.d/search-disabled-repos.conf. Then it worked for me.

Comment: For arm64, the url is http://mirror.centos.org/altarch/7/extras/aarch64

Answer (score 7):

Had this problem too when trying to install Docker.  This worked to get fuse-overlayfs

```
sudo yum install fuse3-devel
wget http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/extras/x86_64/Packages/fuse-overlayfs-0.7.2-6.el7_8.x86_64.rpm
sudo yum localinstall fuse-overlayfs-0.7.2-6.el7_8.x86_64.rpm
```

I got the package url from http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/extras/x86_64/Packages/

The next thing missing for me is `slirp4netns >= 0.4`.  I'm going to try the same trick.  And yes, that did work and the docker install went through

```
 sudo yum install docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io
```

Comment: On Oracle linux, the fuse3-devel package is not available by default. You have to add the centos extras repo as noted in the solution provided by Bruno Unna before the required docker dependencies can be installed.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem installing docker version 20 in Oracle Linux 7.9. Installing version 19 instead, there is no problem with dependencies and to install packages from CentOS Extras repository is not needed.

```
sudo yum install docker-ce-19.03.9 docker-ce-cli-19.03.9 containerd.io docker-compose-plugin
```

*edit*

To show all available versions

```
yum list docker-ce --showduplicates | sort -r
```

Answer (score -6):

Install the fuse3 libs package. That would provide the missing dependencies. And then try the fuse overlay package before proceeding to the docker install