# Oracle Linux Server 7.9 how solve problem with dependencies when yum install docker-ce-20.10.5?

Tags: linux, docker, centos7, oraclelinux

I have OS

```
# cat /etc/os-release
NAME="Oracle Linux Server"
VERSION="7.9"
ID="ol"
ID_LIKE="fedora"
VARIANT="Server"
VARIANT_ID="server"
VERSION_ID="7.9"
PRETTY_NAME="Oracle Linux Server 7.9"
ANSI_COLOR="0;31"
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:oracle:linux:7:9:server"
HOME_URL="https://linux.oracle.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugzilla.oracle.com/"

ORACLE_BUGZILLA_PRODUCT="Oracle Linux 7"
ORACLE_BUGZILLA_PRODUCT_VERSION=7.9
ORACLE_SUPPORT_PRODUCT="Oracle Linux"
ORACLE_SUPPORT_PRODUCT_VERSION=7.9
```

try to install docker-ce-20.10.5

```
# yum install docker-ce-20.10.5 docker-ce-cli-20.10.5    containerd.io -y
```

returned errors

```
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: docker-ce-rootless-extras-20.10.7-3.el7.x86_64 (docker-ce-stable)
           Requires: fuse-overlayfs >= 0.7
Error: Package: docker-ce-rootless-extras-20.10.7-3.el7.x86_64 (docker-ce-stable)
           Requires: slirp4netns >= 0.4
```

fuse3-devel

```
# yum info fuse3-devel
Loaded plugins: langpacks, rhnplugin
This system is receiving updates from Spacewalk server.
Repository docker-ce-stable is listed more than once in the configuration
Available Packages
Name        : fuse3-devel
Arch        : x86_64
Version     : 3.6.1
Release     : 2.el7
Size        : 38 k
Repo        : cmn_ol_7_epel
Summary     : File System in Userspace (FUSE) v3 devel files
License     : LGPLv2+
Description : With FUSE it is possible to implement a fully functional filesystem in a
            : userspace program. This package contains development files (headers,
            : pgk-config) to develop FUSE v3 based applications/filesystems.
```

How solve this problem?

Comment: see : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65878769/cannot-install-docker-in-a-rhel-server , works for me .

Answer (score 4):

Just meet the same problem.

To fix it, Oracle Linux developer repo should be enabled. In the current Oracle Linux version from Oracle cloud it can be done by editing `/etc/yum.repos.d/oraclelinux-developer-ol7.repo`, where in a block `[ol7_developer]` value `enabled` should be set to `1`.